# Comment notification keeps returning

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

For the past 45 minutes, the notification of the most recent comment directed at me keep returning a few minutes after I've dismissed it by clicking on the inbox and viewed the comment.

It doesn't seem to be the case that the comment author has edited the comment so I need to be notified of the change. It has occurred so far with two different comments on different SE sites.

[Why is the logical NOT operator in C-style languages "!" and not "~~"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/399096/why-is-the-logical-not-operator-in-c-style-languages-and-not/399124?noredirect=1#comment877743_399124)

[What do you call the fallacy of thinking that some action A will guarantee some outcome B, when in reality B depends on multiple other conditions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67429/what-do-you-call-the-fallacy-of-thinking-that-some-action-a-will-guarantee-some?noredirect=1#comment186793_67429)

**EDIT**

The problem seems to have gone away. I haven't gotten any duplicate notifications in at least a day.

Comment: Deleted and wrote the same comment again perhaps? Could that be?

Comment: If they did that, the comment timestamp would change.

Comment: Sometimes when I switch to an old tab, the comment notification stays up until I reload the page.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just got a duplicate notification of your comment. Did you delete and rewrite it?

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not talking about the notification staying up. I mean the notification has gone away, then 2-3 minutes later it pops up again on a new page.

Comment: @Barmar No I didn't. You probably discovered a bug.

Comment: This was happening to me with a rep notification. It finally went away after I accessed it from the computer. Were you on mobile the whole time?

Comment: I haven't used the mobile app in weeks or months, I personally find it useless.

Comment: Sorry, should've specified there. I mean mobile web (I agree that the mobile app is worthless).

Comment: Haven't been using mobile web, either. This has all been in Chrome on my Mac.

Comment: I had precisely the same problem. It did not go away even after restarting the browser (which was Firefox on a MacBook pro). The issue only got resolved by accessing the site https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions with my iPhone, logging in and clicking on the notification buttons.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you have any post in that period that was linked under "Hot Network Questions"?

Comment: Yes, both questions I listed above came from HNQ. I also have answers in questions that were recently hot, but have now fallen out of the list.

Comment: No sure if it helps, @schr, but my rep that stuck was from an answer on a HNQ question as well.

Comment: @scohe001 So maybe more than a coincidence? (The downside of getting too much attention? ;-)

Comment: Maybe there is an even bigger bug. So far I hardly paid any attention to the HNQs, but now I looked at the list and there are two LaTeX questions linked, both of which I have the accepted answer for. Is there some bot or even non-bot going berserk?